# Get data from 2 columns from a CSV file. Check whether the entries are same and add the currency amount

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, count

I have a data.CSV file containg the following data

> column1,column2,amount,    column3
>
> name1,empId1,**34.12**,241682-27638-CIGGNT
>
> name2,empId2,**22.14**,241682-27638-OCGGINT
>
> name3,empId3,**18.98**,241942-37190-GGDIV
>
> name4,empId4,**8.98**,241942-37190-GGDIV
>
> name5,empId5,**234.098**,241942-37190-CHYOF

The **bold** entries is the currency amount.I want to add the **column3** and **amount** entries into a dictionary in python.But if the entry in the column3 repeates it should add the currency amount and insert it into the dictionary.

The output should be as below.

```
  {'241682-27638-CIGGNT':'34.12','241682-27638-OCGGINT':'22.14','241942-37190-GGDIV':'27.92','241942-37190-CHYOF':'234.098'}
```

I tried by the below code but it is just updating(overwriting the currency amount) the previous entry(instead of adding it to the previous amount)

```
import csv

path = "file_path"

file=open( path +"data.CSV", "r")
reader = csv.reader(file)

counterlist = {}

for row in reader :

    #print row[3]
    #print row[2]
    if counterlist.has_key(row[3]):
    
        row[2]+=row[3].value
        counterlist.update({row[3]:row[2]})

     else:
         counterlist.update({row[3]:row[2]})

print counterlist
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

# ...

counterlist = defaultdict(float)
for row in reader:
    counterlist[row[3]] += float(row[2])
```